# Should I use utf8 or utf-8-sig when opening a file to read in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I have alway used 'utf8' to read in a file:

```
 with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f, open(filename2, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f2:
      for line in f:
          line = line.strip()
          columns = line.split(' ')
       for line in f2:
          line = line.strip()
          columns = line.split(' ')
```

However, the code above introduced an additional '\ufeff' code at the line of for 'f2':

```
columns = line.split(' ')
```

Now the columns[0] contains this character, while 'line' doesn't have this character. Why is that? Then I switched to 'utf-8-sig', and the problem is gone.

However, the first file reading 'f' and the 'columns' doesn't have this issue at all even with 'encoding=utf8' only. Both are plain text files.

So I have two questions regarding:

1. I am using Python3 and when reading a file, should I always use 'utf-8-sig' to be safe?
2. Why doesn't 'line' contain this additional code, but 'columns' contains it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF-8-encoded files can be written with a signature indicating it is UTF-8.  This signature code is called the "byte order mark" (or BOM) and has the Unicode code point value U+FEFF.  If the file containing a BOM is viewed in a hex editor the file will start with the hexadecimal bytes `EF BB BF`. When viewed in a text editor with a non UTF-8 encoding they often appear as `ï»¿` but that depends on the encoding.

The `'utf-8-sig'` codec can read UTF-8-encoded files written with and without the starting BOM signature and will remove it if present.

Use `'utf-8-sig'` for writing a file only if you *want* a UTF-8 BOM written at the start of the file.  Some (usually Windows) programs, such as Excel when reading text files, expect a BOM if the file contains UTF-8, and assume a localized encoding otherwise.  Other programs may not expect a BOM and could read it as an extra character, so the choice is yours.

So for your two questions:

> I am using Python3 and when reading a file, should I always use 'utf-8-sig' to be safe?

Yes, it will remove the BOM if present.

> Why doesn't 'line' contain this additional code, but 'columns' contains it?

`line.strip()` doesn't remove `\ufeff` so I can't reproduce your claim.  If a UTF-8 w/ BOM-encoded file is opened with `utf8` the first character should be `\ufeff`.  Are you using `print` to display the line?  `\ufeff` is a whitespace character if printed:

```py
>>> line = '\ufeffabc'
>>> line
'\ufeffabc'
>>> print(line)
 abc
>>> print(line.strip())
 abc
>>> line.strip()
'\ufeffabc'
```

Comment: I check the existence of \ufeff using PyCharm debugger.

Comment: Frustratingly, Python's default `json.load` function will throw a cryptic error message when it encounters a utf-8-sig file unless you specifically tell it to read the file with that type of encoding, which can lead to a frustrating debugging session.

Comment: @Pikamander2 always use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` when reading a UTF-8 file.  It removes the signature if it’s there and is otherwise harmless